# Compiler not finding functions declared in header file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, .so

I need some help understanding why this is not working. I have a .h file that declares a function defined within a .so file:

```
/* navApi.h */
void navApi_init();     /* resides in libNavApi.so */
```

and a .cpp file:

```
/* test.cpp */
#include <iostream>
#include "navApi.h"

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "start...\n";
    navApi_Init();
}
```

I compiled using:

```
g++ test.cpp -navApi
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
test.cpp: (.txt+0x1e): undefined reference to `navApi_Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

-- running on linux, ubuntu --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a linker error, not finding `libnavApi.so`

```
g++ test.cpp -lnavApi
```

might work if `libnavApi.so` is in a path that `g++` knows about.

Comment: I put navApi in /usr/bin/ld:
now I get a seg fault.. so I guess the compilation would work